¿Cómo actualizar un registro sin la necesidad de cambiar una foto y/o la huella digital?
Lo que estoy tratando de hacer, es querer actualizar un registro de un gestor y/o alumno sin tener la necesidad de cambiar obligatoriamente una foto y/o una huella digital, como agregar un segundo nombre en el campo de nombres o cambiar la dirección de correo electrónico.

Sin embargo, al dar clic en el botón de "Actualizar Datos", me lanza esa excepción:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.FileInputStream.available()" because "this.m" is null
at vistaInterfaz.FrmModGestor.ActualizarDatos(FrmModGestor.java:410)
at vistaInterfaz.FrmModGestor.actionPerformed(FrmModGestor.java:473)

Me dice que no se puede invocar el FileInputStream porque la variable "m" que esta declarada como el inputFileStream es nulo. Igual pasa lo mismo cuando quiero actualizar un dato de un registro de alumno sin querer cambiar una foto o remplazar una nueva huella digital.

La excepción que arroja porque la plantilla de la huella es nulo:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.digitalpersona.onetouch.DPFPTemplate.serialize()" because "this.template2" is null
at vistaInterfaz.FrmModAlumno.ActualizarDatos(FrmModAlumno.java:530)
at vistaInterfaz.FrmModAlumno.actionPerformed(FrmModAlumno.java:698)

Intenté hacer el código de la respuesta de esta pregunta que tengo ese mismo problema: Error en java al guardar la imagen en mysql
Pero no me dio resultado alguno, procedo a mostrar el código de actualizar registro de modificar gestor:
public void ActualizarDatos(){
    String nombre = txtNombre.getText();
    String ap = txtAP.getText();
    String am = txtAM.getText();
    String sexo = cbSexo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String correo = txtCorreo.getText();
    String telefono = txtTelefono.getText();
    String area = cbArea.getSelectedItem().toString();
        
    if(nombre.isEmpty()||ap.isEmpty()||am.isEmpty()||correo.isEmpty()||telefono.isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Favor de completar los datos para registrar el gestor.");
    }
    else{
        if(sexo.equalsIgnoreCase("Seleccionar") || area.equalsIgnoreCase("Seleccionar")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Favor de elegir el sexo del gestor y su área correspondiente.");
        }
        else{
            if(!validarNombre(nombre.trim())){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El nombre del gestor solo acepta caracteres alfabéticos."
                    + "\n" + "Mínimo de 50 caracteres.");
            }
            else{
                if(!validarAP(ap.trim())){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El apellido paterno solo acepta caracteres alfabéticos."
                        + "\n" + "Mínimo de 50 caracteres.");
                }
                else{
                    if(!validarAM(am.trim())){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El apellido materno solo acepta caracteres alfabéticos."
                            + "\n" + "Mínimo de 50 caracteres.");
                    }
                    else{
                        if(!isEmail(correo.trim())){
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La dirección de correo se escribe de esta forma: ejemplo34_2-1@dominio.com"
                                + "\n" + "el dominio se escribe con caracteres alfabéticos y agregar la extensión que pertenece:" + "\n" + ".com, .gob, .net, .edu" + "\n" + 
                                "en caso de tener otra extensión que representa el país, escribir de esa forma:" + "\n" + ".mx, .ar, .co, .hn, .es");
                        }
                        else{
                            if(!validarTelefono(telefono.trim())){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El no. telefono solo se introduce con caracteres numéricos."
                                    + "\n" + "Ingrese solo 10 dígitos.");
                            }
                            else{
                                try{
                                    PreparedStatement pstmt = Conexion.conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE gestor SET nombre = ?,apePaterno = ?,apeMaterno = ?,sexo = ?,correo = ?,telefono = ?,area = ?,foto = ? WHERE idGestor = '"+idGestor+"'");
                                    pstmt.setString(1, nombre);
                                    pstmt.setString(2, ap);
                                    pstmt.setString(3, am);
                                    pstmt.setString(4, sexo);
                                    pstmt.setString(5, correo);
                                    pstmt.setString(6, telefono);
                                    pstmt.setString(7, area);
                                    pstmt.setBinaryStream(8, m, m.available());
                                    int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos del(a) gestor(a) actualizados correctamente.");
                                    FrmListaGestor flg = new FrmListaGestor();
                                    flg.setVisible(true);
                                    this.setVisible(false);
                                } catch(SQLException ex){
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha generado un error al actualizar los datos del(a) gestor(a), favor de intentar de nuevo"
                                        + "\n" + "o contacte con el administrador de soporte técnico para resolver el problema.");
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El tamaño de la imagen sobrepasa de 1 MB, favor de" + "\n"
                                        + "elegir una imagen mayor a 2 KB y menor a 1 MB");
                                    Logger.getLogger(FrmModGestor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                } catch(IOException ex){
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No ha seleccionado una imagen" + "\n"
                                        + "favor de subir para continuar con el registro.");
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                    System.out.println("Error");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

El código de mostrar foto del gestor en el JLabel:
public void MostrarFoto(String idGestor){
    try{
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Blob imgMuestra = null;
        ImageIcon img = null;
        
        String query = "SELECT foto FROM gestor WHERE idGestor = '"+FrmModGestor.idGestor+"'";
        Statement stmt = Conexion.conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        
        rs.next();
        imgMuestra = rs.getBlob(1);
        long a = imgMuestra.length();
        byte barr[] = new byte[(int)a];
        barr = imgMuestra.getBytes(1, (int)a);
        
        img = new ImageIcon(barr);
        lblFoto.setIcon(img);
        rs.close();
    } catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.println("Error en mostrar la foto" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

Y el de que ejecuta la acción de dar clic en el botón de cambiar foto, aunque no quiero que me obligue a cambiar una foto nueva, pero para que puedan ver de donde sale la variable "m":
if(e.getSource() == btnFoto){
        FileNameExtensionFilter filtro = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Archivo de imagenes (*.JPG;*.JPEG;*.PNG;*.BMP)", "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "bmp");
        JFileChooser archImg = new JFileChooser();
        archImg.addChoosableFileFilter(filtro);
        archImg.setDialogTitle("Abrir archivo");
        int estado = archImg.showOpenDialog(null);
        
        if(estado == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            try{
                m = new FileInputStream(archImg.getSelectedFile());
                this.longi = (int) archImg.getSelectedFile().length();
                Image replace = ImageIO.read(archImg.getSelectedFile()).getScaledInstance(lblFoto.getWidth(), lblFoto.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                lblFoto.setIcon(new ImageIcon(replace));
                lblFoto.updateUI();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FrmModGestor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Error");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }
    }

También les muestro el código de actualizar datos del alumno:
public void ActualizarDatos(){
    String control = txtControl.getText();
    String nombre = txtNombre.getText();
    String ap = txtAP.getText();
    String am = txtAM.getText();
    String sexo = cbSexo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String carrera = txtCarrera.getText();
    String semestre = cbSemestre.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String correo = txtCorreo.getText();
    String telefono = txtTelefono.getText();
    String area = cbArea.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String salon = cbSalon.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String serv = cbTipoServ.getSelectedItem().toString();
    ByteArrayInputStream datosHuella = new ByteArrayInputStream(template2.serialize());
    Integer tamanioHuella = template2.serialize().length;
        
    if(control.isEmpty()||nombre.isEmpty()||ap.isEmpty()||am.isEmpty()||carrera.isEmpty()||correo.isEmpty()||telefono.isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Favor de completar los datos para registrar el alumno.");
    }
    else{
        if(sexo.equalsIgnoreCase("Seleccionar") || semestre.equalsIgnoreCase("Seleccionar") || area.equalsIgnoreCase("Seleccionar")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Favor de elegir el sexo del alumno, como tambien el semestre que"
                + "\n" + "se encuentra cursando, y el area que desarrolla su servicio.");
        }
        else{
            if(salon.equalsIgnoreCase("Seleccionar") || serv.equalsIgnoreCase("Seleccionar")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Favor de seleccionar el hexagono que se ubica el alumno, "
                    + "\n" + "como tambien su servicio que se encuentra realizando.");
            }
            else{
                if(!ValidarNoControl(control.trim())){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El no. control del alumno solo acepta caracteres numéricos."
                        + "\n" + "Ingrese solo 8 dígitos.");
                }
                else{
                    if(!ValidarNombre(nombre.trim())){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El nombre del alumno solo acepta caracteres alfabéticos."
                            + "\n" + "Mínimo de 50 caracteres.");
                    }
                    else{
                        if(!ValidarAP(ap.trim())){
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El apellido paterno solo acepta caracteres alfabéticos."
                                + "\n" + "Mínimo de 50 caracteres.");
                        }
                        else{
                            if(!ValidarAM(am.trim())){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El apellido materno solo acepta caracteres alfabéticos."
                                    + "\n" + "Mínimo de 50 caracteres.");
                            }
                            else{
                                if(!isEmail(correo.trim())){
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La dirección de correo se escribe de esta forma: ejemplo34_2-1@dominio.com"
                                        + "\n" + "el dominio se escribe con caracteres alfabéticos y agregar la extensión que pertenece:" + "\n" + ".com, .gob, .net, .edu" + "\n" + 
                                        "en caso de tener otra extensión que representa el país, escribir de esa forma:" + "\n" + ".mx, .ar, .co, .hn, .es");
                                }
                                else{
                                    if(!ValidarTelefono(telefono.trim())){
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El no. telefono solo se introduce con caracteres numéricos."
                                            + "\n" + "Ingrese solo 10 dígitos.");
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        try{
                                            PreparedStatement pstmt = Conexion.conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE alumno SET noControl = ?, nombre = ?, apePaterno = ?, apeMaterno = ?, sexo = ?, carrera = ?, semestre = ?, correo = ?, telefono = ?, area = ?, salon =?, tipoServicio = ?, foto = ?, huella = ? WHERE idAlumno = '"+idAlumno+"'");
                                            pstmt.setString(1, control);
                                            pstmt.setString(2, nombre);
                                            pstmt.setString(3, ap);
                                            pstmt.setString(4, am);
                                            pstmt.setString(5, sexo);
                                            pstmt.setString(6, carrera);
                                            pstmt.setString(7, semestre);
                                            pstmt.setString(8, correo);
                                            pstmt.setString(9, telefono);
                                            pstmt.setString(10, area);
                                            pstmt.setString(11, salon);
                                            pstmt.setString(12, serv);
                                            pstmt.setBinaryStream(13, m, m.available());
                                            pstmt.setBinaryStream(14, datosHuella, tamanioHuella);
                                            int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();
                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos del(a) alumno(a) actualizados correctamente.");
                                            LimpiarCampos();
                                            if(nivelA == 1){
                                                FrmListaAlumno flal = new FrmListaAlumno(1);
                                                flal.setVisible(true);
                                                this.setVisible(false);
                                            }
                                            if(nivelA == 2){
                                                FrmListaAlumno flal = new FrmListaAlumno(2);
                                                flal.setVisible(true);
                                                this.setVisible(false);
                                            }
                                        } catch(SQLException ex){
                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha generado un error al actualizar los datos del(a) alumno(a), favor de intentar de nuevo"
                                                + "\n" + "o contacte con el administrador de soporte técnico para resolver el problema.");
                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El tamaño de la imagen sobrepasa de 1 MB, favor de" + "\n"
                                                + "elegir una imagen mayor a 2 KB y menor a 1 MB");
                                            Logger.getLogger(FrmModAlumno.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                            ex.printStackTrace();
                                        } catch(IOException ex){
                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No ha seleccionado una imagen" + "\n"
                                                + "favor de subir para continuar con el registro.");
                                            ex.printStackTrace();
                                            System.out.println("Error");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

El código de mostrar la foto del alumno en el JLabel:
public void MostrarFoto(String idAlumno){
    try{
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Blob imgMuestra = null;
        ImageIcon img = null;
        
        String query = "SELECT foto FROM alumno WHERE idAlumno = '"+FrmModAlumno.idAlumno+"'";
        Statement stmt = Conexion.conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        
        rs.next();
        imgMuestra = rs.getBlob(1);
        long a = imgMuestra.length();
        byte barr[] = new byte[(int)a];
        barr = imgMuestra.getBytes(1, (int)a);
        
        img = new ImageIcon(barr);
        lblFoto.setIcon(img);
        rs.close();
    } catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.println("Error en mostrar la foto" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

Y el de presionar el botón para cambiar una foto nueva para el alumno, aunque no quiero hacerlo por el momento:
if(e.getSource() == btnFoto){
        FileNameExtensionFilter filtro = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Archivo de imagenes (*.JPG;*.JPEG;*.PNG;*.BMP)", "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "bmp");
        JFileChooser archImg = new JFileChooser();
        archImg.addChoosableFileFilter(filtro);
        archImg.setDialogTitle("Abrir archivo");
        int estado = archImg.showOpenDialog(null);
        
        if(estado == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            try{
                m = new FileInputStream(archImg.getSelectedFile());
                this.longi = (int) archImg.getSelectedFile().length();
                Image replace = ImageIO.read(archImg.getSelectedFile()).getScaledInstance(lblFoto.getWidth(), lblFoto.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                lblFoto.setIcon(new ImageIcon(replace));
                lblFoto.updateUI();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FrmModAlumno.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Error");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }
    }

Una disculpa por escribir tan larga la pregunta, ya que necesito poner todo el contexto del problema para que se pueda entender, y le agradezco a alguien que me pueda ayudar con este problema.

No segui todo tu codigo.. pero lo que si veo raro es que tu update haga un update de todos los campos.. porque necesitas eso??? si todos los otros campos siguen iguales, no deberias solo actualizar los campos que realmente se actualizaron? de paso, guardar la foto en la DB es una mala idea.. porque implica tareas extras cada vez que necesitas mostrarla.. si estuvieran en el disco, todas esas tareas te las ahorras.. y el disco es un gran gestor de archivos ;)

@gbianchi, Es que se me olvidó tomar captura de el campo de nombres, tenía solo un nombre y el del correo también. Pero, es que la verdad, no quiero que las imágenes estén almacenadas en el disco duro, aunque las tenga, porque un sistema debe de tenerlas en la base de datos, como algunas páginas web que subes una foto y se almacena en la base de datos del sistema.

No.. no se almacenan en la db.. se almacenan en un storage (una carpeta en algun lado) y en la db se guarda la ruta con el nombre... donde fue que leiste que se guardan en la db??? no es una buena practica... para mostrarlas tenes que transformarlas y volver a transformarlas para guardarlas... es algo que no tiene sentido, ya que la web las lee de un archivo...
